# hide top panel in wpf main window

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF. I create a new project in wpf and in mainwindow.xaml I wrote following

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="604" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" IsTabStop="False" Focusable="False">

<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text = "Welcome to XAML Tutorial with VB.net" Height = "20" Width = "220" Margin = "5"/>
    <Button Content = "Ok" Height = "20" Width = "60" Margin = "5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

when i run the window a panel automatically opens at the top as following

[image]

How to hide this? Please help me.

Comment: Not sure what VS version you are using. Generally go to the main menu of VS and open the *Debug* menu. Select *Debug | Options*. This will open the debugger options dialog. Under the *Debugging* section select *Hot Reload*. Then, in the right view, spot the *WPF and UWP* section and uncheck the *Enable in-app toolbar* checkbox. Click *OK* to leave the dialog.

Comment: I am using vs 2017

Comment: Your accepted answer is "wrong". Don't disable the Hot Reload feature. It's important and not necessary to disable it completely. Simply uncheck the *Enable in-app toolbar* box in the *WPF and UWP* section. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68861222/3141792).

Comment: @BionicCode sure i will remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a debugging feature, quite useful at times.

To disable it, **uncheck** the `Enable XAML Hot Reload` under *Tools -> Options*.

[image: XAML Hot Reload]

Comment: No, don't disable the Hot Reload feature. It's important and not necessary to disable it completely. Simply uncheck the *Enable in-app toolbar* box in the *WPF and UWP* section.

Answer (score 4):

Generally go to the main menu of VS and open the *Debug* menu. Select *Debug | Options*. This will open the debugger options dialog. Under the *Debugging* section select *Hot Reload*. Then, in the right view, spot the *WPF and UWP* section and uncheck the *Enable in-app toolbar* checkbox. Click *OK* to leave the dialog.

[image]