# Weird bar showing up after using LiveChart in WindowsForm C#

Tags: c#, livecharts

[Project Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92bjr.png)

After ploting that chart a small bae was shown. (I used CartesianChart)

I do not know what it is. Consequently I did not find any way to remove it!

What is its name and how can I remove it?

I though it is DataTooltip! But, that was something else. I googled my issue, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: That belongs to the attached debugger if you mean the toolbar at the top center. Its actually helpful while debugging. Start without a debugger and you should not see that.

Answer (score 0):

It's only visible in debugging. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68861079/8837661) shows how to remove it for debugging. The actual application won't have it.

*To disable it, uncheck the Enable XAML Hot Reload under Tools -> Options.*